# dataframe.quantile() produce normal distribution from uniform distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to process a column of a dataframe that contains the gradient (called `grad`) of a graph to a new column that will contain the quantile of each entry in the `grad` column that is called `grad_quantile`.

when i use the `loc` method to locate the appropriate entries, starting from the lowest (`0.01`) quantile to the highest (`1.00`) (that way i will not overwrite the lower percentiles as i go).

```
    granularity = 100

    dataframe['grad'] = dataframe[col_name] - dataframe[col_name].shift(1)
    percentile = 1 / granularity
    
    for i in range(granularity):
        current_percent = round(percentile * (i + 1), 2)
        dataframe.loc[dataframe['grad'] > dataframe['grad'].quantile(current_percent) , 'grad_quantile'] = current_percent
```

so the idea is to have `dataframe['grad_quantile]` store all the gradients' percentiles.

i plotted it with:

```
hist = dataframe['tema16_grad_quantile'].plot.hist(bins=100).get_figure()
hist.savefig("myplot.pdf")
```

The result is a uniform distribution:

[image: uniform distribution]

However, I'm interested to extract a normal distribution, is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "extract a normal distribution"? If the data is not normally distributed, why do you expect that one would be shown in the histogram? Are you certain that the data you're trying plot is normal? There's not really a way to "coerce" the data to have any particular distribution.

Comment: The data is uniformly distributed but this Wikipedia page says that a way to transform it exists https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: Now that i think about it, the `quantile()` method by definition makes it uniform by definition. Maybe do you know of another method that can transform it to normal?